# Failed to load resource: Uncaught ReferenceError: InfoBox is not defined at mainMap

Tags: javascript, wordpress, referenceerror, infobox

I know it's to do with the google map API but unsure how to remove/sold the error. Anyone, please enlighten? It's on Wordpress specifically when I do a search.

https://www.madhatgirls.com/

[image]

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
main-map.js?ver=5.2.3:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: InfoBox is not defined
    at mainMap (main-map.js?ver=5.2.3:16)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` is just an ad tracker being blocked by your browser. The Google Map script is not being loaded because you don't have an [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).